# Is there a way I can set user authorization on my website using laravel?

Tags: laravel, authorization

I'm working on the website and, one of the things I want to do is put authorizations on some of the features on the website so that some authorized users can use them and others can see them, but they can't only use them without authorization.

For example, User A can see features 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 but can only access features 1 and 2, and on the other hand, user B can see and use all 5 features.

Can Laravel do that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Laravel can, But your question is very general.

please see the Laravel documentation for that purpose.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Also, you can use the Laravel package
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction

Comment: I have a school website that allows the teacher to post classes and homework to their student at the same time I want the student to see and have the option to post classes with the authorization of their supervisor teacher this is what I meant with my question I hope I made it specific.